# Enable lint in android studio

Tags: android-studio, lint

I hope my question is not  duplicate.

How to enable lint in android studio ???

in my android studio(v 2.3.1) lint is disable and do not show message for me !!!

please help me.

Comment: Are you able to start lint? (Analyze, Inspect Code...) And the Inspection Results are not showing? Choose View, Tool Windows, Inspection Results.

Comment: @sininen hi ....... my android studio do not show lamp for me ......please help

Comment: You cannot find lint as "lint" in Android Studio. Instead you first click "Analyze" in the top Menu Bar and second you click "Inspect Code..." which should start lint and automatically open the Inspection Results window when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your build.gradle file for the `lintOptions` maybe it's disabled there.

Also from the terminal you can run lint in your projects root directory using `./gradlew lint`. If you want to only run lint for debug sources you can use `./gradlew lintDebug`.